# Cannot compute equation, always gives zero

Tags: c++, equation

Did i miss something? The variable percentage_ always equals 0. I've checked nTimes and winnings, they give the correct values as what is being input. Even when I test out a simple equation like, percentage_=1+1, percentage_ will give 0. Can someone help?

```
    #pragma once
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <iomanip>

    using namespace std;


    class GuessMachine
    {
    private:
        int nTimes;
        int winnings;
        string nM[6];

    public:
        GuessMachine();
        void displayPrizes();
        void displayMenu();
        int getInput();
        void checkNumber();
        void checkPrize();
    };



    void GuessMachine::checkPrize()
    {
        MagicNumber mn;
        int prize_=mn.generateNumber();
        float percentage_;

        percentage_ = float (winnings/nTimes*100); //<--On this line percentage is always 0 no matter what winnings and nTimes are
        cout<<"Percentage is "<<percentage_<<endl; 

        if(percentage_ >= 50)
        {
            cout<<"You have scored "<<percentage_<<"% and won "<<nM[prize_];
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"You have scored "<<percentage_<<"%. You lose!!";
        }

        cin.ignore();
        cin.ignore();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
float (winnings) /nTimes*100
```

instead.

Your version still converts an `int` - `0` to a float.

If one operand to `/` is a float, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
percentage_ = float (winnings/nTimes*100);
```

to

```
 percentage_ = (float(winnings))/nTimes*100;
```

since you need to change 1 number to float for the division to work on floats.